# Surface bundle with flat connection and monodromy representation

Tags: geometric-topology, fiber-bundles, low-dimensional-topology

I saw the following statement:

> An $S_g$-bundle $p: E\to B$ admits a flat connection if and only if the
> monodromy representation $\rho:\pi_1(B)\to\text{Mod}(S_g)$ lifts to $\rho':\pi_1(B)\to\text{Diff}^+(S_g)$.

I have no idea why it is true, is there a reference or can you give proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that you have smooth connected manifolds $B$, $F$ and a representation $\phi: \pi_1(B)\to Diff(F)$. This defines the *associated bundle*
$$
E=B\times_\phi F 
$$
over $B$ together with a flat connection $\nabla$ on $E$. Namely, start with the product $\tilde E=\tilde{B}\times F$, where $\tilde{B}$ is the universal covering space of $B$. The fundamental group $\pi=\pi(B)$ acts on the product space diagonally: by covering transformations on $\tilde B$ and via the representation $\phi$ on $F$. This product action is free and properly discontinuous, hence, you form the quotient $E= \tilde E/\pi$. The projection $\tilde E\to \tilde B$ descends to a bundle map $p: E\to B$. At the same time, the product foliation $\{x\}\times F, x\in \tilde B$ on $\tilde E$ descends to a foliation on $E$ which is transversal to fibers of $p$. The tangent distribution of that foliation is your flat connection $\nabla$ on $p: E\to B$.

Conversely, given a flat bundle $p: E\to B$ (i.e. a bundle with a flat connection), you have its holonomy homomorphism $\pi_1(B)\to Diff(F)$.

My favorite reference for this staff is

*Steenrod, Norman*, The topology of fibre bundles., Princeton Landmarks in Mathematics. Princeton, NJ: Princeton University Press. viii, 229 p. (1999). [ZBL0942.55002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0942.55002).

For surface bundles, check also Morita's book

*Morita, Shigeyuki*, Geometry of characteristic classes. Transl. from the Japanese by the author, Translations of Mathematical Monographs. Iwanami Series in Modern Mathematics. 199. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS). xiii, 185 p. (2001). [ZBL0976.57026](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0976.57026).